# IOS Dictionary to php array

Tags: php, ios, arrays

I have IOS dictionary like

```
[{\"my_id_one\":16403,\"my_id_two\":7239}]
```

When I decode using `json_decode`, it returns `null`.

What is best way to decode it to convert it to a PHP array?

Comment: Works fine for me... https://3v4l.org/8SPnd

Comment: you have to un-escape slashes, if your example is correct. what is the origin of above string?

Comment: If you want to escape the `"` make sure you use `"` to enclose the string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`stripcslashes()`:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php)

```
$str = '[{\"my_id_one\":16403,\"my_id_two\":7239}]';
$str_unescaped = stripcslashes($str);
$array = json_decode($str_unescaped, true);

print_r($array);
```

This outputs:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [my_id_one] => 16403 [my_id_two] => 7239 ) )

Comment: yes it works when you create string in PHP as you did. but when a dictionary is submitted by IOS, it won't decode properly. I have already tried this but didn't work. 

When i test it with RESTclient, it works but in case IOS, i won't.

I also tried all methods on 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php


Nothing get work and then i finally post my question to stackover.
anyway thanks for the help